# How to run pry with bundler without Gemfile

Tags: ruby, bundler, pry

I have a Rails app with gems installed in `vendor/bundle`. I have `pry` gem installed in `/usr/local/bin/pry`. I tried to run `pry` with Rails by doing:

```
pry -r ./config/environment.rb
```

but in this case, bundler not does not see the local gems.

How can I use pry with a Rails app without adding it to `Gemfile`?

Comment: **Why**?? The whole point of bundler is to manage your dependencies like this. You could just add: `gem 'pry', group: [:development, :test]` to the `Gemfile`.

Comment: Of course `bundler` does not see local gems. If it did, then that would defeat its whole purpose. (To be a dependancy manager.)